# How to Convert a Set to another flattened Set using Java Stream

Tags: java, collections, stream

I have a `Set` of object `Car` which has two attributes `int carId, Set<Long> carSN`

```
1, [123, 789]
2, [456]
3, [123]
```

I need to convert that to a `Set` of new object called `CarFlattened` which has two attributes `int carId, Long carSN` such that the new set of `CarFlattened` will be

```
1, 123
2, 456
3, 123
1, 789
```

What is the easiest way to do that using Java Streams ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `flatMap`:

```
List<CarFlattened> flattened = cars.stream()
        .flatMap(car -> car.carSN().stream().map(sn -> new CarFlattened(car.carId(), sn)))
        .toList();
```

Note that I created some records for `Car` and `CarFlattened` for quick testing; replae the `carSN()` and `carId()` methods as needed.